# CakePHP 1.3: Protect Forms From XSS

Tags: php, javascript, forms, cakephp, xss

How can I secure my CakePHP 1.3 site against XSS. Currently I am using $this->Form->create to make the form and I've also tried adding Security to the Components array without any success. Supposed I load the following javascript code into my comments box, that code goes thru all the way to the  database and if I approve that comment, it will show a button where comment is supposed to be returned. And if I click on it, an alert box will popup with XSS Alert?

```
<form>
    <input type="button" onclick="alert('XSS Alert?')" value="Confirmation Alert">
</form>
```

How Can I secure my CakePHP site and prevent things like there from happening.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CakePHP will not protect you against that.

The Security component is there to make sure your form was not tampered with.

You will need to use php built-in functions like htmlentities() or CakePHP Sanitize class.

You can either do it in a beforeSave, beforeValidate callbacks or at the view-level if you want to keep the original data.

http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1185/html

http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Comment: I was able to use Sanitize::clean in my controller functions where I feel I need protection like `edit` and `add`. It seems to do the trick for me as all tests that I did using XSS passed. I had no more issues. Do you believe that is enough?

Comment: It should be enough, but data manipulation should happen in the model.